# handling right click with single button mouse (tablet)

Tags: mouse, tablet, panel, dock

I'm currently trying to put together a config to facilitate accessing a Linux machine over VNC from a tablet. But I've got a problem with how to deal with right clicks (although I haven't actually *tried* touching the screen with my other hand ;). While I could amend the vncclient to (temporarily) switch the left and right mouse buttons, this then requires a user-interface running outside the view port, using up valuable screen space.

I believe it's possible to remap the behaviour at the server end using xmodmap or xinput, and I could add a button on the taskbar/panel to run a script for this (already planning such for switching between windows and running xrandr to rotate screen) the downside is that the image will be static (i'd like some visual feedback on the state) and I'm not sure if it will handle the right click to restore the settings.

(currently the plan is to use Openbox as the WM and most likely fbpanel, but this is not set in stone)

Anybody come up with a better solution?

Comment: What kind of tablet? It makes a difference.

Comment: On Apple devices a two-finger click/tap does a context click in most VNC applications.

Comment: For simplicity I'm probably going to go down the noVNC route - which makes it much simpler to swap the event strings in Javascript, or use xmodmap -e 'pointer=3 2 1....' serverside (with a timer to restore)

Comment: @bahamat: **any** kind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a better solution, xmodmap it is.